# Linearly independent sequences

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $t$ be an element in the interval $(0,1)$.
>   Suppose we create the sequence $\alpha=(t,t^2,t^3,\ldots,t^n,\ldots)$. Is the set 
>   $\{\alpha \mid 0< t <1\}$ linearly independent?

I tried it but I'm stuck.
Can you give me a little hint please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Fix the formatting in your question. You've posted five other questions with unreadable plaintext, all of which have been fixed by other people. Proper math formatting is not optional for this site.

Comment: I've edited your question, please check whether or not I've interpreted what you meant correctly.

Comment: $\;\alpha\;$ is linearly independent...in what linear vector space? It seems pretty obvious, but as this is a beginner's question it'd be better to be crystal clear with this. Also, why not subindex $\;\alpha\;$ with $\;t\;$ to be *surely clear* it depends in on it? Like $\;\alpha_t\;$ , say?

Comment: The space i refer to is the space of bounded sequences

Comment: @user359315 Over what field? The reals? With what operations? The usual componentwise ones or what?

Comment: The sequences of the set are of the form α(i)=(ti,ti^2,ti^3,,,ti^n,,,,,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, suppose that it isn't, then there are $t_1<t_2\dots <t_n$ and non-zero reals $b_1,b_2\dots b_n$ such $b_1t_1^k+b_2t_2^k+\dots + b_nt_n^k=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z^+$.

This would imply $b_1(\frac{t_1}{t_n})^k+b_2(\frac{t_2}{t_n})^k+\dots + b_{n-1}(\frac{t_{n-1}}{t_n})^k + b_n=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z^+$. This is impossible as:

$\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}b_1(\frac{t_1}{t_n})^k+b_2(\frac{t_2}{t_n}^k)+\dots + b_n=0+0+\dots+b_n=b_n\neq0$

Comment: Why linear *dependence*, after ordering the parameters $\;t_i\;$ in ascending order, would imply that **precisely** the last coefficient $\;b_n\;$ is not zero? Or to begin with, why all the coefficients zero? I think this only requires a minor adjustment...

Comment: It doesn't, you can assume all coefficients are non-zero, I am taking a finite subset of the vectors. I am taking all of them nonzero

Comment: This answer shouldn't be downvoted since, as a hint, is a rather very good one, and as a complete answer it only lacks some few details that can be safely left to the OP to complete. +1